Logistic Regression (Predictor Variables Splitting)
I'm trying to run logistic regression on a Mass Shootings dataset having a binary variable corresponding to whether or not there was a high or low number of victims (total_victimsrate_binary). For whatever reason when I run the glm model the predictors are separating into their respective individual categories. Even when I call as.factor on the variables nothing happens. If you could provide any guidance or assistance on how to fix this I would be so grateful.
I've tried as.numeric on the numeric variables such as the age of the shooter and that worked, but as.factor on the categorical predictors is not working.


It looks like you need to clean up your data since R is recognizing "religious" and "Religious" as different variables.  Capitalization and punctation matter in R!  Without seeing a sample of your data it is difficult to make other suggestions.

Please use minimal reproducible examples others can run using copy & paste. Show desired output entirely. Use dput() for data & specify all non-base packages with library().

One parameter per category (minus the reference) is how any model would be parametrized, so I'm not sure what you expect instead?
